# XAMPP mailtodisk feature

Tags: php, email, xampp

This is probably a stupid question but I can't seem to find an answer anywhere. I have made a PHP mail script on localhost and I need to test it, all the emails are being forwarded to the 'xampp/mailoutput' file and I can view them as .txt files. Does this mean that my script is working fine? Or do I need to set up a tool such as 'TestMailServerTool' to test properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yup If you're getting mail output that means php is sending emails successfully.

If you want to get proper email functionality you have to setup an SMTP server in your Windows System. You can also use other SMTP servers like gmail, yahoo or use one which is provided to you by your ISP or your Web Hosting providers.